# VerneMQ TLS configuration gives error handshake failed using letsencrypt

Tags: ssl, mqtt, vps

I am running vernerMQ on a VPS with ubuntu 18.04 as OS, I made certification using OpenSSL then copied the cert files from
/etc/letsencrypt/live/$mydomain/*.pem
to
/etc/vernemq/
I am using this configuration for SSL:

```
listener.ssl.cafile = /etc/vernemq/chain.pem
listener.ssl.certfile = /etc/vernemq/cert.pem
listener.ssl.keyfile = /etc/vernemq/privkey.pem

listener.ssl.default = 0.0.0.0:8883
```

User and password is set in a passwd file.
the problem is when I try to connect to the server from an esp8266, it gives me this error:

```
BSSL:_wait_for_handshake: failed
BSSL:Couldn't connect. Error = 'Unknown error code.'
```

here is the esp8266 code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include<WiFiManager.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

//Enter your wifi credentials
const char* ssid = "ssid";  
const char* password =  "ssidpass";

// A name for our device
const char* deviceName = "devicename";

// Our mqtt server Adress and port
const char* mqttServer = "mydomain";
const int mqttPort = 8883;

// a user defined on our server with it's password for login purpose
const char* mqttUser = "user"; //User
const char* mqttPassword = "pass"; //Password

// our gpio
#define ESP8266_LED (0)

// this is ca Certificate used as SSL key
const char caCert[] PROGMEM = R"EOF(
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    cert content : cert.pem
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
)EOF";

/* MQTT broker cert SHA1 fingerprint, used to validate connection to right server */
const char mqttCertFingerprint[] = "fingerprint";
     
/* Other globals */
X509List caCertX509(caCert);        /* X.509 parsed CA Cert */
WiFiClientSecure espClient;         /* Secure client connection class, as opposed to WiFiClient */
PubSubClient mqttClient(espClient); /* MQTT Client connection */
String clientId = "ESP8266Client-"; /* MQTT client ID (will add random hex suffix during setup) */



void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
  
  // prepare GPIO0
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
 // digitalWrite(0, LOW);


  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

/*#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG*/
  Serial.print("Connecting");
/*#endif*/
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
/*#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG*/
    Serial.print(".");
/*#endif*/
  }
/*#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG*/
  /* When WiFi connection is complete, debug log connection info */
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected, IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  setClock();
/*#endif*/
 /* Configure secure client connection */
  espClient.setTrustAnchors(&caCertX509);         /* Load CA cert into trust store */
  espClient.allowSelfSignedCerts();               /* Enable self-signed cert support */
  espClient.setFingerprint(mqttCertFingerprint);  /* Load SHA1 mqtt cert fingerprint for connection validation */
  
  /* Optionally do none of the above and allow insecure connections.                                             
   * This will accept any certificates from the server, without validation and is not recommended.
   */
  //espClient.setInsecure();

 /* #ifdef TLS_DEBUG
  /* Call verifytls to verify connection can be done securely and validated - this is optional but was useful during debug */
  verifytls();
/*#endif
  /* Configure MQTT Broker settings */
  mqttClient.setServer(mqttServer,mqttPort);
  mqttClient.setCallback(subCallback);

    /* Add random hex client ID suffix once during each reboot */
  clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX); 

}



void loop() {
    /* Main loop. Attempt to re-connect to MQTT broker if connection drops, and service the mqttClient task. */
  if(!mqttClient.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  mqttClient.loop();
}

/*#ifdef TLS_DEBUG
/* verifytls()
 *  Test WiFiClientSecure connection using supplied cert and fingerprint
 */
bool verifytls() {
  bool success = false;
    
/*#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG*/
  Serial.print("Verifying TLS connection to ");
  Serial.println(mqttServer);
/*#endif*/

  success = espClient.connect(mqttServer, mqttPort);

/*#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG*/
  if (success) {
    Serial.println("Connection complete, valid cert, valid fingerprint.");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Connection failed!");
  }
/*#endif*/

  return (success);
}
/*#endif*/

void reconnect() {
  /* Loop until we're reconnected */
  while (!mqttClient.connected()) {
/*#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG*/
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT broker connection...");
/*#endif*/
    /* Attempt to connect */
    if (mqttClient.connect(clientId.c_str(),mqttUser,mqttPassword)) {
/*#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG*/
      Serial.println("connected");
/*#endif*/
      /* Once connected, resubscribe */
      mqttClient.subscribe("user/home1/esponoff");      
    } 
    else {
/*#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG*/
      Serial.print("Failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(mqttClient.state());
      Serial.println(". Trying again in 5 seconds...");
/*#endif
      /* Wait 5 seconds between retries */
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

// Set time via NTP, as required for x.509 validation
void setClock() {
  //get the time
}

void subCallback(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length)
{
 //to do
}
```

the same config is working with mosquitto but not with verneMQ

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue. The only difference is I created my certs (OpenSSL)
I have configured vernemq the exact same way. MQTT.fx is connecting fine, node-red is connecting fine, mosquitto_pub and mosquitto_sub are connecting just fine.

Its only ESP8266 with WiFiClientSecure espClient; is not connecting.
However, if I change my broker to mosquito then ESP also connects without an issue.

Please let me know if you have already solved it using VerneMQ. If not we can exchange our experiment results and see if anything comes up.
Thank you.

Comment: Tuhin Sengupta, this does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)